# Check if filename contains Umlauts in php

Tags: php

Is there any way, to check in php if a filename has Umlauts?

Answer (score 2):

There's a quick way to do this:

```
$s = 'äëüïö';

if (preg_match('/&[a-zA-Z]uml;/', htmlentities($s, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'))) {
    echo 'Filename contains umlaut';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$your_text = "hiÍ :)";
$umlauts = "Ŕ,Á,Â,Ă,Ä,Ĺ,Ç,Č,É,Ę,Ë,Ě,Í,Î,Ď,Ň,Ó,Ô,Ő,Ö,Ř,Ů,Ú,Ű,Ü,Ý,ŕ,á,â,ă,ä,ĺ,ç,č,é,ę,ë,ě,í,î,ď,đ,ň,ó,ô,ő,ö,ř,ů,ú,ű,ü,ý,˙,Ń,ń";
$umlauts = explode(",", $umlauts);
foreach($umlauts as $umlaut){
    if (false !== (strpos($your_text, $umlaut))){
          echo "found ".$umlaut."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

working [demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/3e201.php)